# react-konva: disable canvas element devicePixelRatio scale

Tags: canvas, konvajs, react-konva

I'm using react-konva

when I render a `<Stage />` with width:750, it will render a `<canvas />` element with width 750 * devicePixelRatio

```html
<Stage width={750} />
```

will render (in iPhone 7)

```html
<canvas width="1500" />
```

How do I disable this behavior ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import Konva from 'konva';

Konva.pixelRatio = 1;
```

But in the case image on HDPI display (such as retina) will look blurred.

Comment: But also prevent 'layer.getContext().getImageData' from returning completely wrong results on those HDPI displays or any other zoomed browser window. This should be the default setting.